# Powercast Powerharvester Chipset PCC110 Issues

Tags: rf, energy-harvesting

I recently picked up a PCC110 [datasheet](http://www.powercastco.com/PDF/PCC110-PCC210-Overview.pdf), an RF energy harvester. I assumed the 3 pins would correspond to GND, Antenna, and Vout (the datasheet does not specify).

I attempted all of the permutations for the pins in a relatively radio noisy location, but I was unable to detect any current (uA range) across a simple load. I wasn't expecting the rated max of 50mA, but not even a uA?

Is there something I am missing? Do these devices work in ambient radio environments, without the Powercast booster station? The device is quite small and I had a difficult time soldering the connections; could I have damaged the device with the heat?

Comment: That's a surprisingly thin datasheet.  Do you have an option to switch to one of their other ICs, which have better documentation?

Comment: That's the next step, which may or may not ever happen, mostly due to the cost per unit ($30 vs $2). For the immediate future, I'm stuck with this device.

Comment: Pretty miserable- like some other kinds of chips. They want to deal with big volume potential and for you to sign an NDA.

Comment: Just a few thoughts for your testing, the current it can deliver with background RF is probably tiny so maybe try charging a cap rather than a direct load and a transmitter that outputs a constant carrier (like a UHF CB) that you can hold fairly close by might be useful.

Comment: Just a heads up, that is not the actual datasheet for the powercast P1110 or the P2110. That is simply an overview of them both. This is what you are actually looking for for the P1110: http://ca.mouser.com/ds/2/329/P1110-datasheet-694.pdf and for the P2110: http://ca.mouser.com/ds/2/329/P2110-datasheet-1690.pdf  When mouser tries to teach you more about the PCC110, they actually try and teach you about a different product.

Comment: @user01 Did you ever get any power out of this chip? What antenna did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PCC110 is stated as operating from -17dBm upwards - to expect that level of RF signal prevailing even in a so-called "noisy" environment is hoping a lot. At (say) 1GHz and at (say) 10 metres distant from a 1 watt transmitter, the free-space link loss in dB is: -

32.45 + 20 log\$_{10}\$(MHz) + 20 log\$_{10}\$(km) =

32.45 + 20 log\$_{10}\$(1000) + 20 log\$_{10}\$(0.01) =

32.45dB + 60dB - 40dB = 52.45dB

Total power one could expect to receive is 30dBm (1W) - 52.45dB = -22.45dB i.e. below the lower limit for the device to work. It is intended for RFID applications is my conclusion.